# Where are the JRoute::_() - function? in joomla

Tags: php, joomla, content-management-system

Why in the class JRoute there is no method with _ , but we use it??, the class JRoute only extends the JObjects, but where are the _ function? in joomla

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What version are you using? If you go [to the API page](http://api.joomla.org/__filesource/fsource_Joomla-Platform__librariesjoomlamethods.php.html), you have this source code:

```
class JRoute
{
    /**
     * Translates an internal Joomla URL to a humanly readible URL.
     *
     * @param   string   $url    Absolute or Relative URI to Joomla resource.
     * @param   boolean  $xhtml  Replace & by &amp; for XML compilance.
     * @param   integer  $ssl    Secure state for the resolved URI.
     *                              1: Make URI secure using global secure site URI.
     *                              0: Leave URI in the same secure state as it was passed to the function.
     *                             -1: Make URI unsecure using the global unsecure site URI.
     *
     * @return  The translated humanly readible URL.
     *
     * @since   11.1
     */
    public static function _($url, $xhtml = true, $ssl = null)
    {
        // Get the router.
        $app = JFactory::getApplication();
        $router = $app->getRouter();

        // Make sure that we have our router
        if (!$router)
        {
```

So the method is there, defined right from the beginning (line 33 more or less).
 Look here for the method's documentation : http://api.joomla.org/Joomla-Platform/JRoute.html#method_

Comment: i am using 1.5 \libraries\joomla\application\router.php - in this path i am searching for that method, but i can't find it

Comment: It's in `libraries/joomla/methods.php`. If you get familiar with the find command (UNIX), you'll find navigating the joomla source a LOT easier; e.g. `find /path/to/joomla/ -name '*.php' -exec grep -l '^class JRoute$' {} \;`